# What does a 10 beep error code on AMI BIOS mean?

Tags: bios, motherboard, flash

In AMI BIOS list shows a flash write error. In every day operation the flash is not being written to.

So I think the BIOS is failing and the code is casual. I want to know if that makes sense.

Model is an old (2nd generation) [Biostar H61MHB](https://%20Thanks.) motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

According to
[Computer POST and beep codes](https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm#ami),
10 beeps mean a battery problem.

Check if you need to replace your battery.

Comment: There should be an error in Biostar manual. After I check, if it solves the problem or not I will update you if it is ok with you. That will take a day or two. Is for a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Ten short beeps mean that there has been a CMOS shutdown register read/write error. This beep code is usually caused by a hardware failure with the AMI BIOS chip.

A motherboard replacement will usually solve this problem, although it could be caused by a damaged expansion card in rare situations.

Before you go replacing things, start by clearing CMOS and reseating all the expansion cards.

[Source](https://www.lifewire.com/amibios-beep-codes-2624543)